# no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'book' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')

Tags: c++, structure, c++14, codeblocks

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;

   struct book
    {  int bookid;
       char title[20];
       float price;
    }b2;

 int main()
   {  
     b2={100,"c++ by saurabh",105.2}; //values initialised during variable declaration
 
     cout<<"\n"<<b2.bookid;
     cout<<b2.title<<"  "<<b2.price;
     return 0;
     getch();
   }
```

This above code shows error in output like this:

> C:\Users\shandude\Documents\codeblock\cprog\struct2.cpp|13|error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'book' and '')|
>
> C:\Users\shandude\Documents\codeblock\cprog\struct2.cpp|5|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '' to 'const book&'|

Comment: What do you think `b2={100,"c++ by saurabh",105.2}; ` is supposed to do?

Comment: Off topic but the last two lines `return 0;` and `getch();` should be reversed. `getch();` will do absolutely nothing. The application will return before this line is ever called. Also: having `using namespace std;` in global scope is never a good idea nor good practice.

Comment: Should code _initialize_ `b2` (part of `b2` creation) or _assign_ a value to `b2 (value after creation)?

Comment: There may be a narrow conversion from `double` to `float` (though in practice it is usually not because `105.2` is a constant expression and the conversion does not cause overflow usually), so you'd better change `float` to `double` in your example to make people focus on the problem of character array, which is more essential.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
b2 = book{100,"c++ by saurabh",105.2};
```

**PS**

I would recommend changing the member variable `title` to a `std::string`. Use of `char` array to represent strings in user code is an anachronism in the year 2017.

```
struct book
{
   int bookid;
   std::string title;
   float price;
};
```

Comment: Upvoted for the right answer at the top. But, I disagree that `char` arrays are entirely anachronistic. They are still widely used on memory-constrained embedded systems, or where systems may need to be safety-critical or real-time/deterministic, so as to avoid unpredictable dynamic allocation under-the-hood.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not initialization but an *assignment*, because `b2` was already declared earlier.  You need to initialize at the point the variable is declared:

```
   struct book
   {   int bookid;
       char title[20];
       float price;
   } b2 = {100,"c++ by saurabh",105.2}; //values initialised during variable declaration

 int main()
 {  
     cout<<"\n"<<b2.bookid;
     cout<<b2.title<<"  "<<b2.price;
     return 0;
     getch();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize `b2` by `list initialization`. You can read the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to see how to initialize it.
There are many methods. A simple way is:

```
book b2{100,"c++ by saurabh",105.2};
```

Comment: `b2` already exists. The code is trying to *assign* to it, which is different to initialization

Comment: your solution provided me the exact answer what exactly I where i confused ,Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What complier do you use?

After removing `#include <conio.h>` and replacing `float` with `double`, Clang and VC++ both accept this code while GCC complains. I think it is a bug for GCC.

Although this is not an initialization, it is equivalent to call the assignment operator with the initializer-list as an argument. The parameter of the assignment operator is `const book&`, and use this initializer-list to initialize this reference is well-defined. The program is also well-defined.